# Why should I be concerned with supporting really outdated browsers?

Tags: browser

It seems every resource regarding things like CSS3 and HTML5 nag me about particular things not being implemented in older browsers, and hacky workarounds. Really who uses IE 9 or 10 anymore anyway? IE11 is out, Edge is default on W10, and I assume most / all people use it. To me it seems to make the most sense to simply make the page render properly on the latest Chrome (what I use), Firefox, Edge, and Safari..

Ughhh apple. My understanding is that the Windows version of Safari is very outdated and trying to get a (questionably obtained) image of macOS working in a VM has been unsuccessful. I'm not spending a dime for any Apple products just to test my site on their browser. So what can I do in order to test how my site will work in it?

Comment: Why is this question receiving downvotes? I got advice on my last question to break it up into smaller questions, now I can't do that since I'm temporarily banned from asking questions! Please rather than downvote, give me feedback and I can try to improve the question(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your question...

> Who uses IE 9 or 10 anymore anyway?

Typically, people with older Windows systems. This is important for your website based on whether or not IE 9/10 users will be accessing the website that is being supported. (A review of your website's web logs can shed light on this.) If your website is an internal intranet site, then an organization's IT department may dictate the browsers that users can use. However, large eCommerce websites will often support older browsers out of fear of losing customers to rivals.

Regarding your second question...

> How do I go about ensuring the site is functional and looks reasonably
>   good on apple products conveniently, without any apple products while
>   on a minimal budget?

Without actual Apple products, something that emulates these displays is needed. One option is the "Inspect" option with the Chrome browser. (Display your website on Chrome, right-click, select "Inspect".) Inspect allows you to choose between a Desktop or Mobile display. With a Mobile display, you also have the option of selecting several Apple displays (e.g. iPhone, iPad, etc.). This is probably the next best thing to having the actual Apple device and its display for website testing.

[image]

Comment: So then I suppose this is just one of those things where I need to assess the customer base and support browsers / devices accordingly? Which is more or less what I figure. How do I go about ensuring the site is functional and looks reasonably good on apple products conveniently, without any apple products while on a minimal budget?

Comment: Thanks for the additions! I have been using inspect element for testing the responsiveness of my site, but I should have been more clear what I was asking. I am concerned about the way apple browsers parse CSS / HTML. I see that Edge, IE, and Firefox all make my site look slightly different from Chrome I suppose due to differences in the way the CSS interpreter is implemented (requiring me to use variations of the CSS attributes for each browser). I have heard that Safari is notorious for not following standard conventions and web "standards." This is where my concerns stem from.

Comment: A variant of the Safari browser can be installed on Windows. We use it for testing our website. It may not be exactly like Safari on a Mac OS system, but it is probably very close.